# How to transform this lambda code to method reference in Java?

Tags: java, lambda

I have a method reference question in Java.

I want to transform this lambda code:

```
Collections.sort(trends, (map1, map2) -> (int) ((long) map2.get("pageview") - (long) map1.get("pageview")));
```

How to use `Integer::compareTo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to user method reference "Integer::compareTo" try this:

```
Collections.sort(trends, Comparator.comparing( map -> -map.get("pageview").intValue(),
                Integer::compareTo));
```

Comment: thank you.. this code is only available in ascending order.

Comment: @khasui  You can negate; `-map.get("pageview").intValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(trends,
    (map1, map2) -> {
        Integer i1 = ((Long) map1.get("pageview")).intValue();
        Integer i2 = ((Long) map2.get("pageview")).intValue();
        return i2.copmareTo(i1);
    }
);
```

In this way, you can conver your `long` values to `Integer`s and compare them.

Comment: thank you, but this answer is not use method reference.

Comment: @khasui What do you mean? Did not you want to use `compareTo`?

Comment: I suppose by "method reference" @khasui means using existing method in Integer class witch you can just call in such way Integer::compareTo